# Getting element before parent

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following dom tree:

```
<tr class="tomatch" id="123"></tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <span class="matching"></span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have a `$(this)` object set to `.matching` element, and I have to get `.tomatch` element from it. How can I do this?

`parent()` won't work, I tried using `.prev()` or `prevUntil('.tomatch')`, but it doesn't work either. Same thing with `.closest('.tomatch')` and `.parents('.tomatch')`.

How can I do this? I have to match the first element before tr parent, because this structure is repeatable.

Comment: What about first finding tr, then it's parent and then .tomatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest` and `.parents` are for finding elements that are ancestors of the specified element, but the element you want is a sibling of an ancestor. So you need to do it in two steps -- first go up to the ancestor, then go to the previous element from there.

```js
$(".matching").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest("tr").prev().attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tomatch" id="123"></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span class="matching">Click here</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```